# get_duration() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: python, librosa

```
def decoding_stems(file_name):
  audio, sr = sp.read_stems(file_name, sample_rate=22050)
  
  swap_ad = np.swapaxes(audio, 1 , 2) # swaps the first and second axis because most libraries execpt num channels in the second axis and the data in the first
  duration = lb.get_duration(swap_ad[1])
  
  duration_length = (duration // 0.6) * 6 # rounds the song duration to be divisilbe by 6 so that each sound segment is in equal length

  return stft_frame(file_name, int(duration_length), 6)
```

this is the code that I ran for getting de constructed files. When I called this and ran for the train code

```
train_audio_data = []

for i in range(len(train_song_names)):
  
  file_path = path + '/train/' + train_song_names[i] + '.mp4'
  audio_seg = decoding_stems(file_path)
  
  
  train_audio_data.append(audio_seg)
```

it ran but gave an error for the test part

this is the code for the test part

```
test_audio_data = []

for i in range(len(test_song_names)):
  
  file_path = path + '/test/' + test_song_names[i] + '.mp4'
  audio_seg = decoding_stems(file_path)


  
  test_audio_data.append(audio_seg)
```

the error that I got was

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-3f8fadcdbe66> in <cell line: 6>()
      7 
      8   file_path = path + '/test/' + test_song_names[i] + '.mp4'
----> 9   audio_seg = decoding_stems(file_path)
     10 
     11 

<ipython-input-12-359828c0d17d> in decoding_stems(file_name)
     10 
     11   swap_ad = np.swapaxes(audio, 1 , 2) # swaps the first and second axis because most libraries execpt num channels in the second axis and the data in the first
---> 12   duration = lb.get_duration(swap_ad[1])
     13 
     14   duration_length = (duration // 0.6) * 6 # rounds the song duration to be divisilbe by 6 so that each sound segment is in equal length

TypeError: get_duration() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. The error message (final line) is pretty explicit, and the stack trace points precisely at the line of code which triggered the error. Do you need help with some other part of your code ?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `duration = lb.get_duration(swap_ad[1])`, exactly what do you think this means? Specifically, what do you think the `swap_ad[1]` part should accomplish, and why do you think it makes sense to put something there? Do you understand what the error message means? Specifically, do you understand what a `positional argument` is? In your own words, where the code says `lb.get_duration(swap_ad[1])`, how many positional arguments do you believe there are, and what are they? According to the error message, how many should there be?

Comment: In your own words, what does `lb.get_duration` mean, and how do you know that there is such a thing? I assume that you know about it, because you read some documentation. **According to that documentation**, how should the code look?

Comment: Assuming *lb* is an alias for *librosa*, have you considered reading [this](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.get_duration.html#librosa.get_duration) ? If you do, you'll notice that *get_duration()* doesn't take any positional arguments which is exactly what the error message is telling you

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```py
import numpy as np
import librosa as lb
import soundfile as sp

    
def decoding_stems(file_name):
    audio, sr = sp.read_stems(file_name, sample_rate=22050)
      
    swap_ad = np.swapaxes(audio, 1, 2)  # swaps the axis for compatibility
    # Ensure you select a single channel for duration calculation
    duration = lb.get_duration(y=swap_ad[1][:, 0], sr=sr)
      
    # Adjust the duration for segmentation
    duration_length = (duration // 0.6) * 6
    
    return stft_frame(file_name, int(duration_length), 6)
```

Comment: This may resolve the issue but doesn't explain how or why